# CSS sourcemaps and in-browser Sass editing

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools

I've been following two articles about how to start editing scss files on chrome canary (not livereload.com)

https://medium.com/@toolmantim/getting-started-with-css-sourcemaps-and-in-browser-sass-editing-b4daab987fb0

and this one

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors

I added my workspace and the browser is actually reading my file like in the following:

[image]

And then when I click into sources i can modify the content like in this picture:

[image]

I can change the css here and it's fine and it's updating my scss file from Chrome to file.

**The issue**

When I go to the **elements inspector** (first tab on devTools) and I try to change anything on that. The **styles.scss** becomes automatically **styles.css** and then I am not able to modify anything on the elements inspector that will change my scss file.

Also when I change anything on my scss file (using sublime text 2). The browser is not reloading my css, so it's not working from file to Chrome.

Are this two thing a bug? Is it mean to work like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit hard to make the model-based editing (in the Elements panel) play well with source-mapped code, since different users may expect different behaviors (moreover, editing a variable-based property value in SASS may assume editing it directly or editing the variable value instead.) Thus, we have not decided on how this should work, and the CSS-SASS link is just broken at the moment of edit (since the CSS no longer corresponds to the SASS source it was generated from.)

Please star https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257778 and leave a comment saying what kind of behavior you expect.